# Launch4J splash file

Tags: launch4j

I am trying to use launch4j and found the following example for the splash image. What are the allowed image format, other than *.bmp?

```xml
<splash>
  <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/build/splash.bmp</file>
   <waitForWindow>true</waitForWindow>
   <timeout>60</timeout>
   <timeoutErr>true</timeoutErr>
</splash>
```

Comment: gif seems to be an option see http://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/129/ where a gif file was used as an example

Comment: I tried editing xml file manually and adding gif filepath. But it doesn't work.